# copy data using scriptella based on if a foreign key exists

Tags: java, scriptella, janino

i am trying to copy data from a table to another , but before doing it , i need to check whether the selected codearticle exists already as keys in another table.So i will copy them if exists , and i won't copy them , if not existing then i log them 
Here what i did any help to test if selected codearticle exists or not .

Here what i did

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE etl SYSTEM "http://scriptella.javaforge.com/dtd/etl.dtd">
<etl>
    <description>
        test script Pour table ARTCAB
    </description>
    <connection id="in" driver="oracle"
        url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE" user="IPTECH" password="IPTECH" />
    <connection id="out" driver="postgresql"
        url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/gemodb" user="postgres"
        password="maher" />
    <connection id="janino" driver="janino" />
    <query connection-id="in">
        select CODEART,CAB from IPTECH.TMP_ARTCAB ;
        <query connection-id="out">
            select id from public.articles ;

            <query connection-id="janino">
                import java.io.*;
                import java.lang.*;
                Boolean result= false ;
                Object objGold =get("CODEART");
                Object objLocal =get("id");
                if(objGold.equals(objLocal))
                {

                System.out.println("equals);

                result=true ;}
                else{
                System.out.println("not equal");

                result=false ;
                }
                set("result", result);
                next();


                <script connection-id="out" if="result">

                    INSERT INTO public.cabarticle
                    (id ,
                    is_enabled,cab_article,article_id) values (1, TRUE,cast(?CAB
                    as
                    bigint),cast(?CODEART as bigint));


                </script>

            </query>
        </query>
    </query>
</etl>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE etl SYSTEM "http://scriptella.javaforge.com/dtd/etl.dtd">
<etl>
    <description>
        test script Pour table ARTCAB
    </description>
    <connection id="in" driver="oracle"
        url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE" user="IPTECH" password="IPTECH" />
    <connection id="out" driver="postgresql"
        url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testMonoprix2" user="postgres"
        password="maher" />
    <connection id="log" driver="text" url="./logging.log" />
    <connection id="janino" driver="janino" />
        <query connection-id="out">
        select id from public.articles
        <query connection-id="in">
            select CODEART,CAB from IPTECH.TMP_ARTCAB
            <query connection-id="janino">
                set("result",get("id").equals(get("CODEART")));
                next();
                <script connection-id="out" if="result">
                    INSERT INTO public.cabarticle
                    (is_enabled,cab_article,article_id)
                    values
                    (TRUE,cast(?id as bigint),?id)
                </script>
                <script connection-id="log" if="!result">
                    $CODEART,$CAB n'ont pas été copiés
                </script>
            </query>
        </query>
    </query>

</etl>
```